# Telegraf.js Как загрузить в бот несколько изображений группой?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram, telegraf

Всем привет!

Проблема такая:

Есть ctx.state.photos, массив

По событию 'photo' я добавляю в него изображения.

bot.on('photo', (ctx) => ctx.state.photos.push(ctx.message.photo)

Если я добавляю одно изображение, то все ОК. Но если изображений несколько (выбрал за один раз несколько изображений на устройстве), то в массив добавляется только одно изображение из выбранных.

Как сделать так, чтобы все они оказались в массиве?

Comment: судя по всему, выбранные «несколько медиа-файлов» в бота приходят раздельно https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/906

Comment: Спасибо, да, эту ссылку я посещал. Честно говоря, не совсем понял, что они там решили)). Это не проблема телеграфа, это потому, что сгруппированные фотки передаются раздельно.

Comment: Я добавил в функцию вывод в консоль, пробую отправить боту группу из трёх фоток. Консоль отрабатывает 3 раза. Но добавление фотки в массив происходит только 1 раз. Добавляется только последняя.

Comment: думаю, потому что ctx разный для каждого отдельного вызова обработчика события